# Dispatcher doesn't trigger

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-context

I'm trying to combine Context and useReducer in Typescript
i have two contexts
// BookContext.ts

```
export const BookContext = createContext<{ books: Book[] }>({ books: initialBooks });
export const BookDispatcherContext = createContext<Dispatch<Actions>>(() => {});
```

// App.tsx

```
export type Actions =
  | { type: "added"; payload: Book }
  | { type: "deleted"; payload: number };

type State = {
  books: Book[];
};

function reducer(state: State, action: Actions) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "added":
      return { ...state, books: [...state.books, action.payload] };
    case "deleted": {
        console.log('asdasd');
        return {
            ...state,
            books: state.books.filter(book => book.id !== action.payload)
        }
    }
    default:
      console.log("nothing");
      return state;
  }
}

export default function App() {
  const initialBooksState = {
    books: initialBooks,
  };

  const [booksState, dispatcher] = useReducer(reducer, initialBooksState);

  return (
    <ChakraProvider>
      <div className="container">
        <BookContext.Provider value={{ books: booksState.books }}>
          <BookDispatcherContext.Provider value={dispatcher}>
            <Home />
            <Finished />
          </BookDispatcherContext.Provider>
        </BookContext.Provider>
      </div>
    </ChakraProvider>
  );
}
```

dispatcher context passes through Home and Finished where booksContext displayed with map and BookCardChakra.tsx template for Book card

/// BookCardChakra.tsx

```
export default function BookCardChakra({ book }: { book: Book }) {
    const dispatcher = useContext(BookDispatcherContext);

    const handleDeleteButton = (bookId: number) => {
        dispatcher({type: 'deleted', payload: bookId});
    }

    return (
            ...
            <Button variant="ghost" colorScheme="blue" onClick={() => handleDeleteButton(book.id)}>
            Delete
            </Button>
        .....
  );
}
```

I put clg inside 'deleted' case in reducer function and noticed that case didn't trigger after click on delete button

sources / recommendations / answer